# I've forgotten the password to my wallet but can still access it, can I get my Bitcoins out?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have forgotten the password that I created for my wallet. I can, however, open my bitcoin-qt software successfully and see my transactions etc.

I know I can't recover or brute-force my password. Can I move my Bitcoins from this wallet to a new wallet (where I'll take better care of my password)? How?

Comment: Update: I hate being senile. I eventually remembered where I securely stored my password and was able to retrieve. Lucky me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but there is no way to spend the coins without the password.  However if your password was of poor quality you may be able to use hacking tools to brute-force it.

Importing the coins to another wallet won't help... it would have the same password.